# How to return multiple arrays in static int method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

How to add multiple arrays to return?
 
I want to return the array `a` and the array `output`.
I added int [] [] in the method, but I don't know how to add the return though

```
public class Bubble 
{
    public static int[][] bubbles( int[]a)
    {
        int output[]= new int [2 ];

        Random g = new Random();
        a = new int [4];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
        { a[i] = g.nextInt(4)+1;}
        int count1=0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
        { a[i] = g.nextInt(4)+1;}
        int swap = 0;

        for ( int pass = 0; pass < a.length ; pass++ )
        { 
            for ( int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++ )
            {
                count1 ++;
                if ( a[ i ] > a[ i + 1 ] ) 
                {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = temp;
                    swap++;
                    output[0]=swap;
                    output[1]=count1;
                }
            }   
        }
        return (output);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible best solution is the one [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337141/2835625).

Change your method signature to

```
 public static Object[] bubbles(int[] a)
```

and return your result like

```
 return new Object[]{a, output};
```

if you want to use the return values of your method you do it like this.

```
 // somewhere in your code
 Object[] res = bubbles(yourArray); 
 int[] a = (int[]) res [0];
 int[] output = (int[]) res[1];
```

Comment: Thank you ! And how can I call the return to print the two arrays?

Comment: i've updated my answer accordingly. But, I would suggest you to get familiar with basic Java-programming concepts, instead of copying and pasting code snippets. For example notice the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You've realized that in order to return two arrays you'll need to return a single object containing both, and you've prepared by making your return type `int[][]`.  Now, in place of `return (output)`, you can do:

```
int[][] result = new int[2][];
result[0] = a;
result[1] = output;
return result;
```

or

```
return new int[][]{a, output};
```

Call it like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3};  
int[][] bubResult = bubbles(arr);
System.out.println("Array of random numbers that was "a" in bubbles:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bubResult[0]);
System.out.println("Two-element array that was "output" in bubbles:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bubResult[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you ! And how can I call the return to print the two arrays?

Comment: Amended my answer

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you do not need to return both. You already have `a`. 
`int[] a` is mutable so it will be changed by `bubbles` method. 
Just have bubbles return output :

```
public static int[] bubbles( int[]a)
```

and **remove** the initialization of `a` from bubbles:

```
// a = new int [4];
```

and use `bubbles` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int [4];
    int[] output = bubbles(a);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));  
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**
However, if you do need to return two `int[]` objects from `bubbles`, you can do it in many ways, for example bu using a `List`:

Change the signature of `bubbles` to return a list :

```
public static List<int[]> bubbles()
```

and create `a` object with in `bubbles`:

```
int[] a = new int [4];
```

and add the needed code to return a `List` :

```
    List<int[]> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    returnValue.add(a);
    returnValue.add(output);
    return returnValue;
```

Use it by :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<int[]> returnValue = bubbles();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(returnValue.get(0))); //prints a
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(returnValue.get(1))); //prints output
}
```